Check numbering of list items with XSLT
I have got lists with two types of list markers, namely numeric (1., 2., 3., etc.) and alphabetic [a), b), c), etc. or aa), bb), cc), etc.]. I want to check whether each item of a list is numbered subsequently according to its list marker type.
This means in numeric lists a subsequent item should be numbered as n+1 plus a dot, where n is the number in the current item's term and n+1 would be the number in its following-sibling::*[1]/self::item/term.
In alphabetic lists the following-sibling::*[1]/self::item/term should contain the next letter(s) in alphabetical order from the current item/term plus a closing parenthesis. So for example after "b)" would follow "c)" and after "cc)" would follow "dd)".
I do not want to change the numbering using xsl:number, but just check and document the errors found and ideally their locations.
The input format would look like this:
<list>
  <item>
    <term>1.</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
  <item>
    <term>3.</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
  <item>
    <term>4.</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
</list>


Or:
<list>
  <item>
    <term>a)</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
  <item>
    <term>b)</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
  <item>
   <term>d)</term>
   <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
</list>

Or:
<list>
  <item>
    <term>aa)</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
  <item>
    <term>cc)</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
  <item>
    <term>dd)</term>
    <p>jhjhjh hjkjkjkj</p>
  </item>
</list>

These input samples deliberately contain errors that should be detected and located.

Use numbering to check if the given item/term is the same as the outcome of numbering

'after "cc)" would follow "dd)"': Isn't alphabetic numbering using cc) followed by cd)?

I'm afraid this is not the case. The basic rule is a) > b) > c) > d) etc. When one of these items has an embedded list, the character would be doubled: aa) > bb) > cc) > dd) etc.

Seems like a task for Schematron e.g.
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="item[term[matches(., '^[0-9]+\.$')]][position() gt 1]">
            <assert test="
            let $number := term => substring-before('.') => xs:integer(), 
            $number2 := preceding-sibling::item[1]/term => substring-before('.') => xs:integer() 
            return $number = $number2 + 1">item with <value-of select="term"/> doesn't have the right number.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>

Sample fiddle.
For your alphabetic schema perhaps the following
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="item[term[matches(., '^[0-9]+\.$')]][position() gt 1]">
            <assert test="
            let $number := term => substring-before('.') => xs:integer(), 
            $number2 := preceding-sibling::item[1]/term => substring-before('.') => xs:integer() 
            return $number = $number2 + 1">item with <value-of select="term"/> doesn't have the right number.</assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context="item[term[matches(., '^[a-z]+\)$')]][position() gt 1]">
            <assert test="
            let $index := term => substring-before(')') => string-to-codepoints(), 
            $index2 := preceding-sibling::item[1]/term => substring-before(')') => string-to-codepoints()
            return every $bool in for-each-pair($index, $index2, function($a, $b) { $a = $b + 1 }) satisfies $bool">item with <value-of select="term"/> doesn't have the right term.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>

helps, sample fiddle is online.
As for the error with Schxslt2, I think it is a bug in the template schxslt:failed-assertion-content of transpile.xsl that can be fixed as
  <xsl:template name="schxslt:failed-assertion-content" as="node()+">
    <xsl:sequence select="@flag"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="@id"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="@role"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="test" select="@test => replace('\{', '{{') => replace('\}', '}}')"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang" select="schxslt:in-scope-language(.)"/>
    <alias:attribute name="location" select="{($schxslt:location-function, 'path')[1]}(.)" xsl:use-when="not($schxslt:streamable) or exists($schxslt:location-function)"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="schxslt:report-diagnostics"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="schxslt:report-properties"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="schxslt:report-message"/>
  </xsl:template>

Bug is already fixed in Schxslt2 1.2.2, I have incorporated that version as an option in the Schematron fiddle, the sample now works.

This is a very good idea! Using Schxslt, I could extract the locations from the SVRL output. Would there be a comparable approach for the alphabetic list markers, where I could not apply arithmetic operations?

@WolfgangSchindler, I first thought Siebe's suggestion to compare to a suitable xsl:number result would be a good starting point but on further thought I am not sure about your numbering scheme, I think xsl:number format="aa" would give e.g. aa, ab, ac.

This looks quite interesting! I have never seen a way to apply calculations to letter sequences. When I use schxslt to apply this Schematron to a sample file, I get the following error message:
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -xsl:checkList.xsl -o:report.xml gaga.xml
Error at char 303 in svrl:failed-assert/@test on line 1 column 4199 of checkList.xsl:
XPST0008  Variable $a has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

The problem seems to lie in $a in this line of code:
<svrl:failed-assert test="let $index := term =&gt; substring-before(')') =&gt; string-to-codepoints(), $index2 := preceding-sibling::item[1]/term =&gt; substring-before(')') =&gt; string-to-codepoints() return every $bool in for-each-pair($index, $index2, function($a, $b) { $a = $b + 1 }) satisfies $bool" xml:lang="">

@WolfgangSchindler, that is an odd error as I tested the code in the online fiddle with SaxonJS and Schxslt. I am not sure why you get that, which Saxon version is that, which Schxslt version have you used to compile the Schematron to XSLT?

It's schxslt2-1.1 and SaxonJ-HE 12.5

And in the online fiddle, it's indeed working perfectly :)

@WolfgangSchindler, currently I am inclined to say it looks like a bug in Schxslt2 but I need to look at that in some more detail and then probably see what David Maus, the creator of Schxslt, thinks about it. It works with Schxslt1

Many thanks for taking care of that!!!

Yes, I think it is a bug at https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt2/blob/main/src/main/resources/content/transpile.xsl#L599, the test attribute is copied to a literal result element without escaping the (possible) curly braces of the XPath expression, subsequently the XSLT processor treats the attribute of the literal result element as an attribute value template and tries to evaluate anything in curly braces. So Schxslt2 would need to escape the value of the test attribute when copying it to the literal result element.

David has confirmed it is a bug https://todo.sr.ht/~dmaus/schxslt2/1#event-397820

And a new release fixing the issue (which affected more than the test attribute) is already on Maven https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/name/dmaus/schxslt/schxslt2/1.2.2/.

I have updated to the new release of schxslt and it's working perfectly. Many thanks for your valuable assistance.
Just a tiny remark: I've got list markers such as 1 > 2 > 2a > 2b > 3 which are correct. Would it totally break the algorithm to accommodate this. If yes, I could just check them manually and comment them out so that I can use the schmeatron.

@WolfgangSchindler, as for the new and more complex case of I've got list markers such as 1 > 2 > 2a > 2b > 3, if you can't solve that yourself then consider to raise it as a new, separate question.

Thanks for your feedback! I will see how far I can go on my own and if I can't solve it, I will raise another question
